# How can I avoid jQuery and bootstrap in html pages rendered by rmarkdown?

Tags: pandoc, r-markdown

I want to produce a simple html page where I want the jquery 1.11.0 and bootstrap library are loaded from a specific CDN in remote. But I don't know how can I modify the configurations in the beginning of a RMarkdown document to remove jQuery and bootstrap.

From http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html I create my own header html file which includes all the css and js references.

```
title: "document"
output:
  html_document:
    mathjax: null
    highlight: null
    self_contained: false
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
```

I disable mathjax and highlight.js but cannot disable jQuery and bootstrap and use my own without loading two versions of them.

How can I disable jQuery and bootstrap so that I can use them in my may spefified in `header.html`?

Answer (score 3):

I just notices in the documentation:
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html

You also need to set

`theme: null`

Comment: Right! Unless you have a template, in which the theme setting seems to be ignored.  Necessary to run html_document with `theme=NULL`, I *think*.  But, yes, I think your answer is essentially correct.

Comment: doesnt work for me, I add theme: null but still I find bootstrap css in the elements